# How to identify which process is writing on encrypted disk with ZFS

Tags: debian, luks, zfs, dm-crypt

My disks (ZFS on Linux on encrypted LUKS) are not staying in standby and I'm not able to identify which process is waking them up.

`iotop` is showing command `txg_sync` which is related to ZFS. So I tried `fatrace`. But even with `fatrace -c` I don't get any output. This is related to ZFS and a known issue.

Next try was using the `iosnoop` script (https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools). With this I was only able to identify that `dm_crypt` is writing when the disks are becoming active again.

So it seems I'm not really able to identify the process nor the file which is accessed due to the combination of ZFS and LUKS.

What else can I do to identify which process is waking up my drives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following you are able to identify I/O per process:

```
cut -d" " -f 1,2,42 /proc/*/stat | sort -n -k +3
```